# Why does running "main" in PowerShell open my mouse properties

Tags: powershell

I was setting up a programming environment and I went to run my `Main.exe` and due to lack of sleep I left out the `.exe`. To my surprise the mouse properties dialog opened up. I knew my hello world app wasn't magically opening up mouse properties so I ran a quick `Get-Command Main` and it spat out `C:\Windows\system32\main.cpl`. So I guess the real question here is why does `C:\Windows\system32\main.cpl` open up my mouse properties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.cpl` extension is for control panel items, and the default "open with" is the `control.exe` executable. So when you enter `main` into your terminal, it is opening `main.cpl` with the `control.exe` executable, which is opens the mouse portion of the control panel. I have no idea why they chose to use `main.cpl` for the mouse properties, but here is a list of various other `.cpl`'s to use with `control.exe`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/149648/description-of-control-panel--cpl-files, also check out: https://www.lifewire.com/command-line-commands-for-control-panel-applets-2626060

I have actually used the `mmsys.cpl` to automate switching of sound devices.

Answer (score 0):

`main.cpl` is the Windows Control Panel module (*.cpl*) for *mouse and input*. As you found, when PowerShell cannot find a suitable command to to invoke for the input--`Main` in this case--it searches for an alternative program in the `PATH`.

It just so happens that the name of this module matches a commonly used naming pattern. *C:\Windows\System32* is typically included in a Windows environment's `PATH`.

```
PS> Write-Output $env:PATH 
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;...

PS> Get-Command Main

CommandType     Name              Version    Source
-----------     ----              -------    ------
Application     main.cpl          10.0.15... C:\WINDOWS\system32\main.cpl
```

The mouse properties is the default view for `main.cpl`, but we can also launch keyboard properties in a similar fashion:

```
PS> main keyboard
```

Or, more correctly:

```
PS> control.exe keyboard
```